# Geodesic distance in de Sitter space

Tags: general-relativity, geometry, de-sitter-spacetime, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Consider $N$ dimensional de Sitter space embedded in $N+1$ dimensional Minkowski space:
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}X^\mu X^\nu=1, \hspace{1cm}\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(-1,1,\dots,1)$$
where I set $H=1$ for simplicity. Given two points in de Sitter space (denoting de Sitter coordinates by lower case $x$, as opposed to capitalized Minkowski coordinates $X$) we define the so-called hyperbolic distance
$$P(x,x')=g_{\mu\nu}x^\mu x'^\nu$$
It is often ([between eqn. 32 and 33](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110007), [between eqn. 2.2 and 2.3](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0112218), [equation 3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2557)) said that this is related to the geodesic distance 
$$ D(x,x')=\int_x^{x'}d\lambda\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx'^\nu}{d\lambda}}$$
by $P=\cos D$. This is independent of the specific coordinates one chooses on de Sitter space. However, I cannot seem to understand how to show this. Can anyone here perhaps enlighten me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is there a choice of induced metric?  Given an embedding and an eveloping metric, there should be exactly one choice of intrinsic metric for the de Sitter space.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer  You can choose different coordinates on the sheet, right? Perhaps you consider that part of the embedding: I probably got the technical definition wrong. I edited the sentence for clarity.

Comment: I just wouldn't call that a different metric.  I would call it the same metric under a different coordinate system

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Fair enough! I'm just using the nomenclature used in my last source (the lecture notes by Akhmedov). Would you have any input on my question, by the way?

Comment: when I have time to go and work it out, maybe.  The trick will be that de Sitter space is defined as a sphere in the D+1 space, and the relationship you have is the relationship between the length of a chord connecting two points and the arc length between the two points.  But I'd want to work out something more careful before posting it as an answer.  Or if the hint helps enough, you could always answer your own question :)

Comment: @JerrySchirmer that argument did help me quite a bit... I can sort of justify it for myself based on analytically continuing from a sphere in Euclidean space, but it's not very precise.