# Wave equation for de Sitter invariant Green's functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, greens-functions, de-sitter-spacetime, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In [several papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2557) [on QFT in de Sitter space](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153524:1/component/escidoc:153523/phd-32-85-ba.pdf) (curvature set to $1$) it is asserted that the Klein-Gordon equation obeyed by the two point function of the free fields:
$$(\square-m^2)G(x_1,x_2)=0 $$
can be rewritten, if the two point function only depends on the geodesic distance $Z_{12}=Z$ between the two points, to the following:
$$\bigl((Z^2-1)\partial_Z^2+NZ\partial_Z+m^2 \bigr)G(Z)=0$$
I tried to trace back the references to the origin of this idea, but it leads to a dead end: a paper from 1968 by Geheniau and Schomblond in a (now) obscure journal from Belgium that I cannot find on the internet. Does anyone have an idea of how to recast the first equation as the second? [My last question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104560/geodesic-distance-in-de-sitter-space) is slightly related. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It just looks like an simplification, like when you reduce $\nabla^2 f(\vec r)$ to an $\frac{1}{r} \partial_r (r \partial_r f(r))$ if $f$ depends only on $||\vec r ||$.

_(I don't know the way to relate geodesic distance, so I can't compute the formulae)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master thesis by J. Hartong, *On problems in de Sitter spacetime physics* has some detailed explanation from Eq 2.5 to 2.6. I was able to get the final answer following his notes.

Two important intermediate steps are:

$\partial_aZ=-l^{-2}(\frac{X^d(y)}{X^d(x)}X_a(x)-X_a(y))$

and

$(\partial Z)^2=l^{-2}(1-Z^2)$,
$\nabla^a(\partial_a Z)=-l^{-2}DZ$

You will need to use
$\Gamma^c_{ab}=l^{-2}(\eta_{ab}X^c+\frac{X_aX_bX^c}{l^2-\eta_{de}X^dX^e})$

The calculation was still long though. I did it step by step and it took six pages and some help with Mathematica.

Comment: Please add in some of the explanation you found therein. Otherwise, this answer should be a comment.

Comment: Hey @han-yan , I am trying to do the same derivation and manage to get the first result $\partial_aZ = ...$. Nevertheless, I am struggling with the second one. Namely $(\partial Z)^2 = g^{ab}(\partial_a Z)(\partial_b Z)$. I am not too sure about which metric to use. We know that $g^{ab} = \eta^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}X^aX^b$ but then, where this is supposed to be evaluated in term of the small $x$ and small $y$. Do we use $g^{ab} = \eta^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}X^a(x)X^b(y)$? Can you guide me through some of the steps ?